# What does "SP18" mean on the name of the certification?

Tags: certification, release-exam

When I took two exams in June I noticed they had "SP18" on the name, as in:

> Exam: Salesforce Certified Platform Developer I (SP18)

What does this SP18 mean? Summer Platform 18? Summer Preview 18?

Comment: It should be SPring 2018. :)

Comment: So Summer would likely show up as SM and Winter as W or WT?

Comment: Spring is SP, Summer is SU and Winter is WI in their abbreviated form on certifications.

Comment: Would you mind posting that as answer? :)

Comment: Possibly the shortest answer, but done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The release version is abbreviated on certifications as below:

> Winter - WI
>
> Spring - SP
>
> Summer - SU